# How do I change linux user within C code?

Tags: c, linux, permissions

How do I change the user that my c program identifies itself as?

A command-line tool I want to invoke automatically requires to be run as a specific user and won't work otherwise.

I have tried using `setuid(0)` but I still don't get the desired results.

The user I want to imitate is not '**root**', but a normal unprivileged, shell-less user. I want to be able to run the binary logged in as the user nobody. I was able to concoct a solution as 'root' using:

**`su -ls /bin/bash -c /binary`** (superuser)

However I want to be able to achieve the same logged in as user **nobody**

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm certain that there shouldn't be a way to do this. If there is, it's a major hole in the OS that needs to be fixed. What you should do is have your program complain and quit if the user doesn't have permissions (perhaps recommend that they use sudo)

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do?  There may be another way than compromising your whole system.

Comment: While of limited importance, I'd just like to point out that everybody is ASSUMING the 'specific user' is root.  I wouldn't be surprised if that is not the case.

Comment: Your are right, the 'specific user' is not root, but a generic user with no shell assigned; however the tool I want to run checks to see if the user that runs it is that specific user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything on the C side. Just change the binary to be owned by the user you want to use, enable the setuid bit in the binary (`chmod u+s`), and you're all set!

(If you don't want any user to be able to run as your designated user willy-nilly, consider using sudo.)

Comment: I was really hoping nobody would write this. Obviously OP knows just enough to get himself rooted as soon as he does this...

Comment: @R.. eep! comment deleted.  My mistake.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone could just become root by putting `setuid(0);` in their program, Unix would be, well, Windows.

Some thoughts:

1. Running external command line tools from C is almost always a mistake.
2. If you really need this command line tool, does the tool really need root permission to work? If not, fix the tool (or go back to step 1 and incorporate the functionality into your own program).
3. If you really need the tool and it really needs root, consider setting up `sudo` permissions for it and running it via sudo.

Given the very basic question you're asking, you should not even attempt to write code that will run as root, so I've omitted any details about how to setup root permissions for your program.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you believe it is possible for a C program in Windows to obtain Administrator privileges just by calling an equivalent to setuid(0).  It's been a long time since Windows 95/98/Me were relevant.

Comment: I was referring to the Windows Vista/7 behavior of popping up a "This operation needs Administrator privileges. Do you want to become Administrator?" window. It should at least have an advanced logic puzzle so users who can't/won't read/understand the message don't just click-through on the "yes" button.

Comment: A ubuntu box pops up a comparable dialog when one starts a system-configuration GUI app.

Comment: If there's any sanity left in the world, it asks for a password, right? Please please tell me it asks for a password...

Comment: Chris, that is because it uses a more sophisticated framework of PolKit than traditional UNIX privellege mechanisms.

Answer (score 6):

To change the current userid:

Firstly, lookup the new userid using `getpwnam()`.  This returns a `struct passwd *pw` and a NULL value will indicate that user doesn't exit.  The `struct` contains the userid (`pw_uid`) and the group id (`pw_gid`) which are needed to perform the change.

`if((pw = getpwnam(userid)) == NULL)
    sprintf(error_msg "Userid '%s' does not exist", userid);`

Then set the group id for the new user

`if (setgid(pw->pw_gid) != 0)
    sprintf(error_msg "setgid() to %d failed", pw->pw_gid);`

Finally, set the user id for the new user

`if (setuid(pw->pw_uid) != 0)
    sprintf(error_msg "setuid() to %d failed", pw->pw_uid);`

Error recovery during this process is messy.  The easiest way is to simply abort if either `setgid()` or `setuid()` fails.  The real problem occurs if changing the group succeeds, but changing the user fails.

Comment: Thank you for not assuming we're all idiots.